# Rational homology of $\Omega^{n+1}\Sigma^{n+1}X$

Tags: homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences, fibration, loop-spaces

I want to know how compute, by induction and using the Serre spectral sequence for homology, $H_*(\Omega^{n+1}\Sigma^{n+1}X, \mathbb{Q})$. 
I know that I have to use the path-loop fibration 
$$
\Omega^{n+1}\Sigma^{n+1}X \to P\Omega^{n}\Sigma^{n+1}X \to \Omega^{n}\Sigma^{n+1}X
$$
Nevertheless I don't know how to make the inductive case, i.e n=1.

Any suggestions?
Somebody knows a reference?